# Происхождение выражения "наше вам с кисточкой"

Tags: фразеология

Хотелось бы узнать происхождение выражения (шуточного приветствия) "Наше вам с кисточкой".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Первая версия. Выражение образовано от формулы приветствия *наше вам!* (из более пространных оборотов *наше вам почтение! наше вам уважение!*) путем шутливого добавления *с кисточкой.* Такое расширение состава фразеологизма не изменило существа его значения, а лишь внесло в него экспрессивность. Имеется в виду, очевидно, кисточка на шапке. Возможно, такое объяснение слова *кисточка* находит подтверждение в варианте приветствия *Наше вашим шляпой машем!*
2. Вторая версия. Выражение, по объяснению известного театроведа В.А.Филиппова - редактора текста отдельного издания пьесы А.Н.Островского "Бедность не порок" (М., 1950, с.70), - часть более пространного приветствия уличных парикмахеров в старой Москве. Зазывая клиентов, они выкрикивали: "Наше вам почтение с кисточкой, с пальцем девять, с огурцом пятнадцать!" Это означало, что брить клиента будут с мылом ("с кисточкой"), а щека при бритье будет оттягиваться пальцем, засунутым клиенту в рот, либо - что будет стоить дороже - использующимся для того же огурцом. (Историко этимологичский словарь "Русская фразеология" А.К.Бириха и др.)

Comment: Полностью поддерживаю второй вариант. Первый - народная этимология, ничего по сути не объясняющая.

Comment: Мне тоже второй вариант нравится больше. Но я специально привела всю словарную статью из указанного словаря.

Comment: А мне больше нравится первый - независимо от ее происхождения, дальнейшее существование этой идиомы обеспечивает явно первый вариант, что, кстати, явно обычно для идиом, вроде того "заруби на носу" и т.п. Так что это таааакой... вопрос... :>